# How to set duration instead of start and finish dates on Angular Gantt

Tags: angularjs, gantt-chart

I'd like to know if it's possible to draw a gantt chart setting an attribute as "duration" instead of providing start and finish date.

For example: Currently I'm drawing my gantt chart like this: 
`{name: 'Task 1', color: '#9FC5F8', from: new Date(2016, 0, 12, 9, 0, 0), to: new Date(2016, 0, 14, 17, 0, 0),
                progress: {percent: 34, color: '#3C8CF8'}, movable: false}`

but I'd like to draw it like this:

`{name: 'Task 1', color: '#9FC5F8', **duration: "90"**,
                progress: {percent: 34, color: '#3C8CF8'}, movable: false}`

I hope what I've requested is possible!
Best regards,

Comment: Don't you need at least one of the dates to go with the duration of the task? Otherwise how should your code know where to start drawing?

Comment: You're right @YannLelong, I forgot to mention that, sorry. I've the duration value calculated already by other process and it's stored in a database, I just wanna show that in the chart. got it?